React native sms retriever giving error [Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/HintRequest$Builder;]
import SmsRetriever from "react-native-sms-retriever";

async function retrieveNumber() {
    try {
      const number = await SmsRetriever.requestPhoneNumber();

      if (number) {
        const numberWithoutCountryCode = number.replace("+91", "");

        setPhoneNumber(numberWithoutCountryCode);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}


The function is returning me an error
[Error: Exception in HostFunction: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/HintRequest$Builder;]

Does anyone know about any fix?
Expected to get the device phone numbers in return.

Are you running on a real device?

Yes running on a real device
